# Python + requests, How I send username & password in POST?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python + requests to integrate with qTest REST API. I have a problem on the first step of the login process.

I need to create a POST massage that looks like that:

```
POST /api/login
Host: nephele.qtestnet.com  
Cache-Control: no-cache  
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded  
j_username= maxmccloud%40qasymphony.com&j_password=p@ssw0rd
```

I did this on python:

```
r = requests.post("http://indegy.qtestnet.com/api/login",data="j_username= maxmccloud%40qasymphony.com&j_password=p@ssw0rd")
print r.text
```

But when I run it it says:

> {"message": "Login failed. Invalid username or password."}

Comment: Change the encoded `%40` to `@`. You may have to place it in a `dict` (test it out). See Muhammad's response.

Comment: Hi. Tried both ways (%40 and @) and still not working. Also tried the dict and the string options and no good.

Comment: @StasM: are you a) certain you have the right hostname in the URL and b) a valid username and password?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just pass the username and password in a dictionary to the `data` argument; `requests` will then encode the information for you. Use *unencoded* data, so use `@` instead of `%40`, for example:

```
data = {
    'j_username': 'maxmccloud@qasymphony.com',
    'j_password': 'p@ssw0rd'
}

response = requests.post(
    'http://indegy.qtestnet.com/api/login',
    data=data
)
```

`requests` will then encode the dictionary and set the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as well.

See the [*More complicated POST requests* section](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) in the Quickstart documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import urllib
r = requests.post("http://indegy.qtestnet.com/api/login",data=urllib.urlencode({'j_username': 'maxmccloud@qasymphony.com', 'j_password': 'p@ssw0rd'}))
print r.text
```

Instead of urlencoding data yourself that you are sending to server you should create a dict of data and url encode it using `urllib` module's `urlencode` method.

Edit:

As @Martijn suggested, requests does urlencoding itself so you can only do:

```
r = requests.post("http://indegy.qtestnet.com/api/login",data={'j_username': 'maxmccloud@qasymphony.com', 'j_password': 'p@ssw0rd'})
print r.text
```

Comment: There is no need to use `urlencode`; `requests` will do this *for you*.

Comment: Hi. Tried both ways (%40 and @) and still not working. Also tried the dict and the string options and no good.

Comment: @StasM Have you tried logging in to api using some REST client like PostMan for Chrome? Are you able to login there?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
r = requests.post("http://indegy.qtestnet.com/api/login",data={'j_username': 'maxmccloud@qasymphony.com', 'j_password': 'p@ssw0rd'})
```

Comment: even a single sentence explanation would be a great improvement for your answer